# Can I do a slideDown from 40px to 600px?

Tags: jquery

I have a div with height 40px; I'd like to do a scrollDown with jQuery from this height to 600px.

How can I do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @jjmontes I think the RTFM rate of the question is the root of the downvoting behaviour.

Comment: I don't understand thise downvote!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) rather than `scrollDown` (or `slideDown`, which I suspect is what you meant). E.g.:

```
$("selector_for_the_div").animate({
    height: 600
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ikowut)

---

**Update**: In a comment on another answer you said:

> Uhm, I think I can't use `animate`! Because I Need that every elements linked to this div (like some div with position absolute) scroll with #myDiv

If you have elements aligned with the div in a way that they don't get moved naturally when the div gets taller (e.g., you've used `position: absolute` or similar), you can animate their `top` (or `bottom`) property at the same time. I'd look at whether it was possible to relate them to the div in a different way, but if you can't, that would be pretty much your only option. It looks something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var theDiv = $("#theDiv"),
      absDiv = $("#absDiv"),
      coords = theDiv.offset(),
      origHeight = theDiv.height();

  absDiv.css({
    position: "absolute",
    left:     coords.left + "px",
    top:      (coords.top + origHeight) + "px"
  });

  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    var height = theDiv.height();
    if (height < 600) {
      theDiv.animate({
        height: 600
      });
      absDiv.animate({
        top: coords.top + 600
      });
    }
  });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ikowut/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) in this way:

```
$('#myDiv').animate({ "height": 400 }, 'slow');
```

Check this sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/4r3rF/

Comment: Uhm, I think I can't use animate! Because I Need that every elements linked to this div (like some div with position absolute) scroll with #myDiv

Comment: @markzzz: I've updated my answer to address your comment above.